# How can I make such a RadioButton?

Tags: android

[image: How can I make such a RadioButton in Android.]

How can I make such a RadioButton in Android.

I made Layout like this, but I think it can somehow be done using the RadioButton class itself. I tried to add child to RadioButton tag but it threw exception

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:text="John Dore"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rb1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score: 11"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:text="Rate: 3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of RadioButton you have made so far in Android?

Comment: at least add some of your work so that we can help....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a xml and use it with a recyclerView.

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="61dp"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="John Dore" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Score: 11   Rate: 3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```